# Replace Main WP Loop Using Plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to replace main WP loop by code in other file, for example:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'tpl/content', 'single' ); ?>
<?php endwhile;
    endif;?>
```

Something like in Woocommerce - i want to replace just "content" of website, header and footer of website should looks like in a theme.
I've tried to use "template_include" and "single_template" but these methods are replacing the whole page.

My main target is to replace "content" using my plugin, no matter what theme is used in WP.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `template_include` and `single_template`? In your plugin's files? What's the context?

Comment: I've tried in plugin, ex.

       function eventorganiser_set_template( $template ){
         $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/templates/test.php'; 
     return $template;
    }
    add_filter('template_include', 'eventorganiser_set_template');

Comment: Ah, okay. See my answer below. You probably don't want to hook in there! It overrides at too high a level.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main target is to replace "content" using my plugin, no matter what theme is used in WP.

If you'd like to alter the "content" of a wordpress page, you should consider either

1. Writing a function and adding that function to the content filter `the_content`, or
2. Creating a Shortcode, to let users choose which page to render your plugin's content on.

   - You could also create a function hooked to `register_activation_hook` that creates a new page with your plugin's shortcode preloaded into it. I'm pretty sure that's what WooCommerce does.

### Writing a function and adding that function to the content filter `the_content`!

```
<?php
// one/of/your/plugin/files.php

function marcin_plugin_content($content) {
    /**
     * Some check to establish that the request is for
     * a page that your plugin is responsible for altering.
     */
    if (true === is_page('marcin_plugin_page')) {
        $new_content = 'whatever it is you do to create your plugin\'s content, do it here!';
        return $new_content;
    }

    // we don't want to alter content on regular posts/pages
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'marcin_plugin_content');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

### Creating a Shortcode, to let users choose which page to render your plugin's content on.

```
<?php
// one/of/your/plugin/files.php

function marcin_plugin_shortcode($atts)
{
    // Borrowed from https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
    $a = shortcode_atts(
        [
         'foo' => 'something',
         'bar' => 'something else',
        ],
        $atts
    );

    // Do whatever you do here to generate your plugin's output...
    $output = 'Foo: "'.$a['foo'].'", Bar: "'.$a['bar'].'"';

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('marcin', 'marcin_plugin_shortcode');
```

Then, your users would be responsible for dropping a `[marcin]` shortcode into a page or post to render the plugin's "content".

If you wanted to create a page automatically for your users, you might try:

```
<?php
// path/to/your/plugin/files.php

function marcin_on_activate() {
    // Maybe do a check that this doesn't exist already to avoid duplicates.. this is just an example!!
    $data = [
        'post_title'    => 'Plugin Page',
        'post_content'  => '[]',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    ];

    // Insert the post into the database.
    wp_insert_post($data);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'marcin_on_activate');
```

I'd encourage you to read the [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) page the WP codex, if you haven't already! Also, so you know where you might be able to hook or filter into:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

A few more references:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

**Edit**: OP writes:

> My bad: "content" - i mean all fields of my CPT: for example: title, description, author, create date, price...number of rooms...etc.

In this case, you'll want to do your template overrides, but then [do as WooCommerce does](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product.php#L23), and include calls to [`get_header()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) and [`get_footer()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) in your templates. Those functions

> Include...the [header/footer].php template file **from your current theme's directory**.

Comment: My bad: "content" - i mean all fields of my CPT: for example: title, description, author, create date, price (based on CMB2), number of rooms (based on CMB2) etc. I'd like to see all these fields here: https://www.screencast.com/t/HReG3kRvfftC Rest of theme should be untouched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited to address this other point. :) Please don't forget to hit 'accept' if it answers your question!